# Angular Selected list data using checkbox persist without using table in primng

Tags: angular, data-persistence, concurrentskiplistmap, primeng-checkbox

I am doing a list of item clicks to show their particular item values using Checkbox List
when I click a Each Check box Item show their separate checkbox List Item in another Column field,
If I select one Item and their Item values, then I move to the next Item checkbox to select their List of Item values, when I back to the previous Selected Item check box . that Item values are not persist in the UI . we are using the primeng library for Check box Item, C[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW9e7.png)

I am trying to Mapping a set of row  values to show their field list values and push the data with Related  row name and persist the selected checkbox value

```
<div class="row pt-3 pb-2 pl-3 pr-0 m-0">
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
                        <p-card header="Schema Name">
                            <div class="m-0" style="margin-bottom: 6px !important;" *ngFor="let content of dbSchemaList; let infoIndex = index">
                            <label class="mb-0 mr-2">{{
                                content.schema_name
                                }}</label>
                            </div>
                        </p-card>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4" >
                        <p-card header="Table Name">
                            <div  class="m-0" style="margin-bottom: 6px !important;"  *ngFor="let category of dbSchemaList" class="field-checkbox">
                                <p-checkbox name="group" [value]="category" (click)="contentEntityAccess($event,category)" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories" [inputId]="category.table_name"></p-checkbox> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <label  class="mb-0 mr-2"[for]="category.table_name"  >{{ category.table_name }}</label>
                            </div>
                            
                        </p-card>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
                        <p-card header="Field List">
                            <div  class="m-0" style="margin-bottom: 6px !important;"  *ngFor="let category of showFieldList.fields_list" class="field-checkbox">
                                <p-checkbox name="group" [value]="category" (click)="contentEntityAccessField($event,category)" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategoriesField" [inputId]="category.field_name"></p-checkbox> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <label  class="mb-0 mr-2"[for]="category.field_name"  >{{ category.field_name }}</label>
                            </div>
                        </p-card>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.